# Comparing a string against a string read from input does not match in Rust

Tags: string, io, rust

In the following code, I was expecting the message “wow” to be printed when the user enters “q”, but it does not.

```
fn main() {
    let mut input = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut input)
        .expect("failed to read line");

    if input == "q" {
       println!("wow") ;
    }
}
```

Why is the message not printed as expected?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your input string contains a trailing newline. Use `trim` to remove it:

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let mut input = String::new();
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut input)
        .expect("failed to read line");

    if input.trim() == "q" {
        println!("wow") ;
    }
}
```

You could see this yourself by printing the value of the input

```
println!("{:?}", input);
```

```
$ ./foo
q
"q\n"
```